# How to get a list of running applications using a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have no idea how to do this inside a fragment. Most of the questions and answers here revolve around a normal activity (extends AppCompatActivity).

What I have is an application with a bottom navigation that uses fragments to switch screens. I tried my best to make things work but nothing works so I decided to ask for help here. I had different errors with different code blocks.

My goal is to get a list of running non-system applications and if possible, how many minutes / hours they were running.

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

public class ListFragment extends Fragment {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_list,null);
        TextView tv1 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.list1);
        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN,null);
        mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        List<ResolveInfo> pkgAppList = getActivity().getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(mainIntent,0);
        for(int i=0; i<pkgAppList.size(); i++){
            System.out.println(pkgAppList.get(i).toString());
        }
        return view;
    }
}
```

This is the last code I tried from around here. The way I understand this is that there are methods and classes used in the code blocks but aren't available for fragments (extends Fragment). What's a possible way around it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this :

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> runningAppProcessInfo = am.getRunningAppProcesses();

for (int i = 0; i < runningAppProcessInfo.size(); i++) {
  if(runningAppProcessInfo.get(i).processName.equals("com.the.app.you.are.looking.for")) {
    // Do your stuff here.
  }
}
```

Hope it helps!